# Merging Table from Scrap using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I want to merge the table multipages from web using Pandas. I managed to create the table from one page, but I need to scrap the table from multipages.

I ran this code and it showed "in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400:"

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

dfs = []


url = 'https://www.emporis.com/city/100422/singapore-singapore/status/all-buildings/{}'


for i in range(1,3):
    df = pd.read_html(url).format(i)

    dfs.append(df)


print(dfs[0].head(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error but I can get the pages as below:

```
url = 'https://www.emporis.com/city/100422/singapore-singapore/status/all-buildings/'


for i in range(1,3):
    df = pd.read_html(url + str(i))
```

if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

`str.format` needs to be called on the url template, not the dataframe

```py
url = 'https://www.emporis.com/city/100422/singapore-singapore/status/all-buildings/{}'


for i in range(1,3):
    df = pd.read_html(url.format(i))
```